# Maintaining grouped UITableViewCell width

Tags: iphone, uitableview, width, cell

I have a grouped UITableView. When the user selects a row I want that cell to get narrower. I have successfully achieved this by:

```
//DidSelectRowAtIndexPath

UITableViewCell *cell = [myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

If (selected == YES) {
    selected = NO;
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, 320, 35);
   } else { 
    selected = YES;
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x,     cell.frame.origin.y, 275, 35);
}

//end DidSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

Now this works like a dream, however when the cell gets scrolled off screen and back again it's at it's full width (320, BTW I'm not saying the visual part is 320 wide. I'm talking about the actual cell frame)
so I added the "cell.frame = blahblahblah" line in my "CellForRowAtIndexPaths method and it makes no difference. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the UITableView has more advanced stuff going on under the hood this disallows me to achieve what I want. So I am trying something similar with a UISwitch.

Answer (score 1):

thats because every time you the cell is scrolled off screen and back again it gets recreated. You need to add check, or tag the selected cell (using an instance variable) and then adjust the width of the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for example:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    if (selectedCellIndex == indexPath.row)
         cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, 320, 35);
    else
         cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, 275, 35);

}
```

hope this helps

Comment: This does not work. My original question was why does this not work? And what would be a workaround to make it work?

Comment: well as i mentioned it doesn't work because the cell gets redrawn every time it scrolls off the screen and back, so its frame will reset (to 320 width on iPhone). This how the `UITableView` is.. The code i mentioned above should work... are you storing the index of the selected cell correctly in a variable?? (`selectedCellIndex`)

Comment: Yes, I even tried writing the "cell.frame = CGRectMake(" line outside of any if statements to make sure it gets executed.

Comment: in my code i might have flipped the `320` and `275` values.. but anyways, try changing the cell's contentView frame instead of the cell's frame. so this `cell.contentView.frame` instead of `cell.frame`.

Comment: No, that does not work either. I tried it both in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and "willDisplayCell forRowAtIndexPath" and no success. Actually "cell.contentView.frame =" didn't do anything at all. "cell.frame =" worked before in my "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: do you mind posting a screen shot of the effect you are trying to achieve.. when its working. thanks.

Comment: I found a better way to achieve what I want. It involves adding a UISwitch to my cell.contentView. Thanks for the help though. Strange why I never got it to work.